# The resource not available error in eclipse ,jsp and tomcat and mysql

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am using eclipse indigo(javaEE) and apache tomcat 7.0.23. the jsp code

```
pstatement = connection.prepareStatement(queryString);
pstatement.setString(1, name);
pstatement.setString(2, city);
pstatement.setString(3, phone);
updateQuery = pstatement.executeUpdate();
```

is giving error as `the requested resource jsp1/prepared_statement_query.jsp is not available`.

The simple `.jsp` file executes properly and shows the successful connection, but not for insertion into the database. I am not getting whether there is problem with the database connection or the running of the server?

Comment: i am sorry i dint add the tags for the code.!

Comment: are you including some other JSP `jsp1/prepared_statement_query.jsp` in the page?

Comment: no.its the only my_try_conn.jsp file and yes the error is 404

Comment: Writing Java code in JSP files instead of Java classes does indeed not always generate very helpful problem indicators. It's then also a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Is it any kind of 404 error? is the file "prepared_statement_query.jsp" not in the place where it should be?

If the error is - "404 Requested Resource Not Found" then find the file in proper place.

And Kindly post the complete stack trace for better understanding of the issue.

Comment: yes.its 404 error.where i am suppose to place that file anyways?i executed simple code without placing it anywhere as i am using eclipse?